# How to create user in Azure Sql Database using Invoke-Sqlcmd (powershell)?

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am trying to create users in Azure SQL Database using PowerShell.
I have stored my sql file in local.

I have tried using `Invoke-Sqlcmd` command:

```
$adminLogin = example@domain.com
$createUserSQLFile = "C:\filepath\createUser.sql"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -U $adminLogin -InputFile $createUserSQLFile
```

But I always get an error

> Cannot open server "domain.com" requested by the login

I have already set up `$adminLogin` user as Active Directory admin. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify you will be using Active Directory authentication.

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential 'username@domainname.onmicrosoft.com'
$Username = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().UserName)
$Password = $($Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
$Database = "testg"
$Server = 'test.database.windows.net'
$Port = 1433
$cxnString = "Server=tcp:$Server,$Port;Database=$Database;Authentication=Active Directory Password;UID=$UserName;PWD=$Password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;"
$query = "CREATE USER YourUser WITH PASSWORD = 'JRxuerCc(q'"
$cxn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($cxnString)
$cxn.Open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $cxn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$cxn.Close()
```

Make sure you also added your public IP address to Azure SQL Database firewall rules.

Comment: Thank you Alberto. When I run this in Azure Functions powershell it is not working. It gives be this error : "keyword not supported: 'authentication'.". This runs fine when I run this is my local powershell